# Custom Pipeline Component to inherent Flat File Disassembler

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk

We will be receiving the CSV file from the receive port with header and body, and I am creating a Custom Pipeline component to check if the body schema has any records if it has any records it will be doing just disassembling and if it has no records it will have to construct a new message and that will be used in sending notifications.

I understand that we can inherit the FFDasmComponent for doing disassemble the received CSV file and convert them in to XML for doing further mapping. But I get below error

[image]

Comment: This is a very clear error message about a missing reference.  What have you done to try and resolve it?  There's nothing special going on here.  That it's BizTalk doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I tried to add the reference for FFDasComp. I tried looking .dll for the pipeline Component, I dont see them

Comment: But where or how did you look?  They're not hidden in any way.  Have you searched for what Assembly FFDasmComp is in?

Comment: Ok I found it now. I added the Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline.Component, i was looking for the FFDasmComp seperately

Comment: @Johns-305 Thank you

Comment: Awesome.  Now you know.